# Reading and Writing from same file?

Tags: c++, file, file-handling, ifstream, ofstream

i am storing some data in the file but after

> if (titlemap.count(words[i]) == 1)

is reached i reopened the file and reading all data in a vector and then storing updated data but
But actually the program is not going into the below loop.

> for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++)
>   Can anyone suggest why is it so? I am very confused and frustrated

---

```
// Cmarkup1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <iostream>
#include"Markup.h"
#include <msxml.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include "functions.h"
#include <map>
#include <fileapi.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    // Open the file for parsing.
    ofstream wfile("title.txt");
    bool check = false;
    string delimiter = " ,:,";

    int results = 0, pages = 1;
    time_t timer;
    timer = clock();
    CMarkup xmlfile;

    unordered_map<string, string> titlemap;
    unordered_map<string, string> textmap;
    vector <string> words;

    xmlfile.Load(MCD_T("simplewiki-latest-pages-articles.xml"));
    xmlfile.FindElem();
    xmlfile.IntoElem();
    int line=0;

    while (xmlfile.FindElem(MCD_T("page"))) {

        xmlfile.IntoElem();
        xmlfile.FindElem(MCD_T("title"));
        MCD_STR(title);
        title = xmlfile.GetData();
        string str(title.begin(), title.end());
        transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
        split(words, str, is_any_of(delimiter));

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            if (titlemap.count(words[i]) == 1) {
                ifstream rfile;
                rfile.open("title.txt");
                vector<string> vec;
                string line;
                while (getline(rfile, line)) {
                    vec.push_back(line);
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++) {
                    if (words[i] == vec[j]) {
                        cout << vec[j] <<"Checking"<< endl;
                        wfile << vec[j] << ",page" << pages << endl;
                    }
                    else
                        wfile << vec[j] << endl;
                    //wfile.close();
                }
            }
            else {
                //wfile.open("title.txt");
                keeponlyalphabets(words[i]);
            titlemap.insert(make_pair(words[i], words[i]));
            wfile << words[i] <<"-page"<<pages<< endl;
            ++line;
            }
        }
            words.clear();
            //cout << str << endl;
            //xmlfile.FindElem(MCD_T("text"));
            //MCD_STR(text);
            //text = xmlfile.GetData();
            //string str1(text.begin(), text.end());
            //transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str1.begin(), ::tolower);
            //str1 = keeponlyalphabets(str1);
            //removestopwords(str1);
            //textmap.insert(make_pair(str1, str1));
            //cout << str1 << endl;
            if (pages > 100)
                break;
            pages++;
            xmlfile.OutOfElem();


        }
    wfile.close();

    //  for (auto it : titlemap)
        //  cout << it.first << endl;
        cout << "Total lines are as:  "<<line << endl;
        /*string input;
        cout << "press s to seach the data" << endl;
        getline(cin, input);
        if (input == "s") {

            string key;
            cout << "Enter Key" << endl;
            cin >> key;
            transform(key.begin(), key.end(), key.begin(), ::tolower);
            size_t temp;
            cout << endl;
            for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++) {
                //temp = it->first.find(key);
                //cout << temp;
                if (it->first.find(key) != std::string::npos) {
                    cout << it->second << endl;
                    results++;
                }
            }

        }
        else
            cout << "Invalid Character Exiting....." << endl;
        timer = clock() - timer;
        cout << "Total time taken by the process is:  " << (float)timer / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
        cout << " Total Results : " << results << endl;
        */
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *it is not running properly* is not a useful problem description. Can you [edit] your post to make the problem you're having more clear? What specifically is the problem you're having with the code you've posted? You've also not asked a specific question. Adding a question mark to a statement (in the title) does not make it a question - it's a statement that is improperly punctuated. You may want to spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [mcve] and [ask], and then come back to [edit] your post to make it more clear.

Comment: Unrelated: Build your own data structure! Good thing!

Comment: for what reason?

Answer (score 0):

You have separate streams opened against the file, with separate *buffers* on each. `write`ing to a file only actually writes to disk infrequently (typically when a buffer fills, which may take a while for small writes, and always just before the file is closed). So when you re-open the file for read, it won't see anything still stuck in user-space buffers.

Just add:

```
wfile.flush()
```

prior to opening for read, to ensure the buffers are flushed to disk and available to the alternate handle.

Comment: @ZeeshanAzhar: Literally just put it on the line before `rfile.open("title.txt");`