# Should I read and write from the same file?

Tags: android, c++

According to [Reading and Writing from same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419346/reading-and-writing-from-same-file), if I use 2 streams (one input, and other output) to read and write from/to a file, I have to flush the output one before opening the input one for reading.

But suppose I'm writing a voice recorder. I might want to go back into some point to play. Flushing the file for reading it then, might not be the best thing to do.

What if, instead of opening `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`, I ismply open an `std::fstream`? Can I write/read at the same time? What should I do?

Currently, I tried writing and flushing to a file, and then reading from that file, but I get 0 bytes read.

**UPDATE:**

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::fstream f;
    f.open("hello.txt");
    std::vector<char> v;
    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(1);
    f.write(v.data(), v.size());
    f.flush();
    f.seekg(0);
    std::vector<char> v2(v.size());
    f.read(v2.data(), v2.size());
    if (f) {
        
    } else {
        std::cout << "did read: " << f.gcount() << std::endl;
    }
    auto* b = v2.data();
    for (int i=0; i<v2.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << b[i] << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`std::fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) supports both reading and writing using the same file stream object. Since you initially didn't show your code, I could only guess that you are not setting the file position pointer properly. When using `seekg()` or `seekp()`, keep in mind that in case of file streams, these both refer to the same position pointer. (For `std::stringstream`, these are different, but not for `std::fstream`.)

To create a file (as opposed to just opening an existing one), you need to specify the `trunc` mode. Also, you need both `in` and `out` modes (for reading and writing). And since you are dealing with binary data (not text), open the file in `binary` mode. In other words, do `f.open("hello.txt", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);`.

Also, when printing the contents of the file, you need to cast `b[i]` to an integer, because the `<<` operator overload used in `std::cout` for a `char` argument will try to print a character, not its numerical value. In other words, do `std::cout << static_cast<int>(b[i]) << '\n';`.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you've got is that these two lines:

```
std::fstream f;
f.open("hello.txt");
```

do not create a new file as you might expect. By default, the parameters of `std::fstream::open` are:

```
void open (const char* filename,
       ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
```

Because of the `ios_base::in` flag, the the file must exist; otherwise the operation will fail and the fail bit of the `fstream` is set. If you had written your code like this:

```
std::fstream f;
f.open("hello.txt");

if (f) 
{
 ...
}
```

you would have found that the `if` statement would have evaluated to false because the stream's failbit is set. It is possible to use `std::fstream` to read and write to a file, but you have to specify that the file is created first if it doesn't exist.

To create a file to read/write if it doesn't exist and destroy its contents, you need to also specify the `std::fstream::trunc` flag:

```
f.open("hello.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
```